# use both url parameter and query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have two action methods in my Products controller. This is my RouteConfig.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

These are the two actions and their working urls.

```
[HttpGet]
//uri:http://localhost:49964/api/products/product?strKey=1
public IHttpActionResult Product(string strKey)

[HttpPost]
//uri:http://localhost:49964/api/products/product
public IHttpActionResult Product([FromBody] Product product)
```

But I also want to use the below url for GET.

```
http://localhost:49964/api/products/product/1
```

But web api responds with,

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
```

Comment: change `strKey` to `id` or do the reverse if you want to keep `strKey`. The route template needs to match up to the action for mapping to work as intended

Comment: but id is placeholder, right? like controller and action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `strKey` to `id` or do the reverse if you want to keep `strKey`.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{strKey}",
     defaults: new { strKey = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The route template needs to match up to the action for mapping to work as intended.

```
//GET api/products/product/1
//GET api/products/product?strKey=1
[HttpGet]    
public IHttpActionResult Product(string strKey)
```

this would however mean that all actions in this route would optionally use `strKey` as a placeholder

Comment: Thnx. I thought that id in route template is a placeholder.

Comment: it is a place holder in the route template. it is just not a reserved one like controller, action or area

Comment: I think the docs have never stressed on that 'reserved' part anywhere. I used to believe it to be a reserved placeholder.